# Listserv Editor role mail address

Tags: email, mailing-list

I am using Listserv 15.5 and I would like to use a mailing list address as editor mail address, however Listserv explicitely warns one from using a mailing list address:

> Important Note: The first editor MUST be an email address that goes to
>   a person, not a file server, list server, mailer, or other automated
>   email address. Specifying a program's mailbox as the primary editor
>   could result in a mailing loop for which L-Soft international, Inc.,
>   could not be held responsible.

What does it mean, that there could be a loop? In which cases? If I enter a mailing list address that doesn't send automatic replies, it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is basically just a legal thing to avoid being sued by stupid users, but of course you have to avoid to be stupid...

A constructed example:

list-a has list-b as an editor, but for some reason, list-a is also member of list-b. If you configure list-a to sent a mail to an editor for confirmation before delivery, list-b will receive and deliver this message again to list-a, which asks lisk-b for confirmation etc.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed something like that, but wasn't sure because the warning is so general.